# How to properly use cookie to store the cart?

Tags: php

so far my situation is when a user press log out , the cart will be destroy/unset.

```
unset($_SESSION[CART_COOKIE]);

setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);**
```

After that , if i log-in with the same user, the cart is removed. as I destroyed it.

so i tried to remove the `setcookie('','','','','','')`, and when i log in with the same user , the cart items still remain there.

but if i log in to another user , I can't add the cart to this specific user , instead I still adding the cart to the previous user.

any tips?

Comment: Why are you using another cookie, if you are already storing information about the cart in the session? Do you want different lifetimes for sessions and carts?

Comment: Cookie does not know about your logged in user, you just set for that browser specific cookie. That's why you get it messed up. If you wish to persist this cart, save cart information to database with reference to user

Comment: @Justinas i have removed the unset and setcookie , so now when i login again with the same user , yes the cart item still remain there. but now when i login to another user , it still using previous cookie , so when i add item it will add to the previous user cart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` superglobals.
The session is manually created, then destroyed when the user logs out -if the website is correctly made : you have to destroy the session manually- or after he left (inactivity timeout - managed by the server configuration).
The cookie is stored on the user's browser and you have to manually create/delete them.

As from what I can see here, you're creating a cookie :

```
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);
```

Then removing a session variable :

```
unset($_SESSION[CART_COOKIE]);
```

These are not the same variable !

To use a cookie to store the cart :

```
setcookie(CART_COOKIE . $user_id, '', 1, "/", $domain, FALSE); //replace $user_id with some specific value for account-less carts
echo ($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE . $user_id]);

unset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE . $user_id]) //if the user destroys his cart, OR if there is already an account-less cart.
```

To use a session variable (recommended) :

```
if (!$user_id) { //If the user is not logged in (account-less cart)
    $_SESSION["cart"] = $value; //store the value un a session variable
    echo ($_SESSION["cart"]); //retrieve the value
} else { //If the user is logged in
    //store the value in a database (+bonus : you can have log data)
    //OR retrieve data.
    //Both need SQL requests.
}
```

Comment: yes i have make a typo mistakes there. right now , i remove the setcookie/unset , now when i add some item to cart and log out , and relogin again , the item is still there. but when i login to other user , it still using previous cookies. any way to set it but not to mess up previous one?

Comment: You could add the user id to the cookie name. Something like :
`setcookie("cart_cookie_" . user_id, "", "", "", "");` But for a cart I would suggest using sessions, and store the cart in your DB if necessary.

Comment: thanks , i will try it , and yeah last time i was using session and it works , but the session will be my backup plan , if this cookie still fail , i will just use back session.